# Spring Batch Rollback Items

Tags: java, xml, spring-batch, chunks

I'm using Spring Batch for import items from XML to database. After import I create log with invalid records. I get these items by configuring skippable exceptions:

```
<batch:chunk reader="reader" processor="processor" writer="writer" commit-interval="10" skip-limit="99999999">
    <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
        <batch:include class="java.lang.Exception"/>
    </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="recordSkipListener"/>
        <batch:listener ref="itemReadListener"/>
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:chunk>
```

My log after step execution:

```
Start time: 30.12.2015 01:05:38
End time: 30.12.2015 01:20:59
Read count: 3842
Skip count: 0
Write count: 3522
```

Skip count calculated by this expression:

```
int skipCount = stepExecution.getReadSkipCount() + stepExecution.getProcessSkipCount() + stepExecution.getWriteSkipCount();
```

"RecordSkipListener" handles all exceptions throwed in processor and writer, but it read, process and write methods are never called during step execution. Only ChunkListener.afterChunkError method is called, but its arguments doesn't contains info about failed record.
Therefore I have two questions:

1. How I can log failed items?
2. Why Spring Batch doesn't implement behavior same as behavior on ItemWriter.write:
   failed chunk are divided onto chunks with size=1 and then processed on dedicated transaction?

// Update

Even if I decrease chunk-size to 1 then about 50 records are not written. And I cannot log their.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your questions in reverse order:

**Why Spring Batch doesn't implement behavior same as behavior on ItemWriter.write: failed chunk are divided onto chunks with size=1 and then processed on dedicated transaction?**

When an exception is thrown during the process or write phase of the step, we can provide the item that caused the error because we have a valid item.  The issue with an exception that occurs during the read phase is that since an exception has been thrown, we don't have an item to give to anyone.  The only way a reader has to communicate what the input was that caused the exception is by embedding information about that input into the exception being thrown.  An example of this is when an exception is thrown during the parsing of a line in the `FlatFileItemReader`, we throw a `FlatFileParseException`.  That exception has both the line number and the contents of the line that caused the exception.  You can use the `ItemReadListener#onReadError` method to catch the exception and obtain the information provided in the exception there.

**How I can log failed items?**

With XML, the ability to provide insight into what went wrong is difficult since it's not really within the reader's control (it's really a function of the unmarshaller and what went wrong there).  The best you can do is to impute the bad record from the record count (via the `ExecutionContext`).  That would tell you what number record caused the error within your XML file.

Comment: Michael, thanks fot the answer, but I found issue of my problem. I described it below

Answer (score 0):

Issue of this problem is that at chunk commiting was exception: length of one of entity fields was exceeded allowed size. In this case processing and writing doesn't retry